# Logged-in users get "Variant Price" in Shopify

Tags: shopify, themes, liquid, price

Is it possible to allow the "Variant Price" only for logged in customers in Shopify and the "Variant Compare At Price" for everyone else?

I tried to change the files theme.liquid and price.liquid in the theme Dawn, but had no success:

THEME: https://github.com/Shopify/dawn